# Как получить и записать значения в строку php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить значения массива $code и записать их в строку, но не работает, как это можно сделать?

```
for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        if (isset($_POST['code'.$i.'']))
        {
            $code[j]= $_POST['code'+i];
            $j++;
        }
    }
    for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        if (isset($_POST['money'.$i.'']))
        {
            $money[j]= $_POST['money'.$i.''];
            $j++;
        }
    }
    foreach ($code as $i => $value) {
        if($code[$i]==1){
            $code[$i]=7;
        }
        if($code[$i]==2){
            $code[$i]=8;
        }
        if($code[$i]==3){
            $code[$i]=9;
        }
        if($code[$i]==4){
            $code[$i]=10;
        }
        if($code[$i]==5){
            $code[$i]=11;
        }
        if($code[$i]==6){
            $code[$i]=12;
        }
        $product+=' '.$code[$i].' ';
    }
```

Comment: `echo implode(" ", $code)`

Comment: @teran как записать это в переменную?

Comment: `$var = implode(...)` как еще то :) вы бы лучше описали вашу задачу, а то какие то сомнительные манипуляции тут приведены в коде )

Comment: собственно ошибка в том, что конкатенация строки делается через `.=`, а у вас суммирование `+=`, т.е. ваш результат всегда будет 0. Но ниже дали правильный ответ. Через `implode` проще и надежней

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implode — объединяет элементы массива в строку (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
echo implode(", ", $code);
```

Comment: не получилось записать, может ещё где-то ошибка? $code[j] исправил

Comment: посмотрите, что в массиве var_dump($code)